# ListView with multiple layouts - how to keep each row in a given layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, baseadapter

I have the following layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textGoesHere"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/row_receive"
        android:text="hello alert" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textGoesHere"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/row_send"
        android:text="hello alert" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to create a ListView that displays these two layouts. Here is my java code, which features the main class, a Message class that stores data from an EditText that the user fills out and which is supposed to populate the ListView, and finally, the custom Adapter class:

```
package com.example.androidlabs;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> listElements = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView theListView;
    Button sendButton;
    Button receiveButton;
    EditText chatText;
    Adapter adapter;
    Message message = new Message();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

        theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatText);
        receiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receiveButton);

        theListView.setAdapter(adapter = new Adapter());

       // sendButton.setOnClickListener(click -> listElements.add("new element"));
       sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                message.setMessage(chatText.getText().toString());
                message.setType(0);
                listElements.add(chatText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        receiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                message.setMessage(chatText.getText().toString());
                message.setType(1);
                listElements.add(chatText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Message {
        private String text;
        private int type;

        public void setMessage(String text) { this.text = text; }
        public String getMessage()  { return text; }

        public void setType(int type)  { this.type = type; }
        public int getType()  {return type; }
        }

    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()  {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)  {
            if (message.getType() == 0) { return 0; }
            else { return 1; }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listElements.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listElements.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return (long) position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View old, ViewGroup parent) {

            View newView = old;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            int listViewItemType = this.getItemViewType(position);

            //make a new row
            if (newView == null)  {

                if (listViewItemType == 0) {
                    newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_send_layout, parent, false);
                }
                else  {
                    newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_receive_layout, parent, false);
                }

            }

            //set what the text should be for this row:
            TextView tView = newView.findViewById(R.id.textGoesHere);
            tView.setText( getItem(position).toString() );

            //return it to be put in the table
            return newView;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the list view to look like this:

[The ListView I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq6nl.png)

But what ends up happening is it changes all of the layouts of the ListView depending on the button the user clicks on:

[The ListView I get if I click on "Send"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbBwN.png)

[The ListView I get if I click on "Recieve"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABJR0.png)

What can I adjust in my code to get the desired outcome? I'm assuming it's something in my getView() method, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: listviews are deprecated, you should consider learning recycler views

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly using the same reference to `Message`:
`Message message = new Message();`

So when a new message gets sent, it also overrides the old message completely. You saved your text by storing it in the `ArrayList` above, so when the layout gets refreshed, it just loads the texts from there, but the message type is read from the single message over and over again...

To fix it, you need the Message to be in an `Array`/`ArrayList` as well. When doing that, I'd also remove the `listElements`-Arraylist, as it just stores the same messages the message itself stores as well... Storing the same data twice is a bad practice, as this can lead to problems when changing only one of them.

So instead of calling the `setMessage` and `setType` method in your `onClickListener`s, create a new instance of `Message`, populate it with data and store it in an `ArrayList`. Then, in your `getView`and `getItemViewType` functions of the adapter, get the required message from the `position`-parameter passed in.